# why the hash-table error is shown while filtering by date using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel-automation

I don't know why i'm getting the keyerror: 'Tested On'

```
msft = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\gomat\\Desktop\\Py TR\\week_06.csv")
msft['Tested On'] = pd.to_datetime(msft['Tested On'],dayfirst =True)
msft = msft[msft['Tested On'].dt.floor('d') == '2018-06-02']
```

Sample Data:

`| Plan | Run      | Status         | Tested On  |
|------|----------|----------------|------------|
| P0   | Agent    | Passed         | 2018-08-11 |
|      | Customer | Failed         | 2018-08-01 |
| P1   | A        | Passed         | 2018-08-02 |
|      | B        | Untested       | 2018-08-11 |
| P2   | C        | Not Applicable | 2018-08-05 |`

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Try `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: @jezrael i'm getting ['sep=', 'Unnamed: 1']

Comment: @gomathisubramanian - sorry, I think `print (msft.columns.tolist())`

Comment: @jezrael Ah i tried with that only

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ using that also gives me the same error

Comment: @gomathisubramanian - error means there is no column `Tested On`, so maybe some data problem if `print (msft.columns.tolist())` is `['sep=', 'Unnamed: 1'] `

Comment: Okay, then i will try with skiprows then

Comment: @jezrael It works, thank you